# CSS: Nav bar delays div

Tags: html, css, css-position

Hello I just started with HTML & CSS and I am currently working on my first website. I have the problem that my nav bar delays the div below it when the div (called Start) is set to relative. I have to scroll to see the full image in the div. But when I set it to absolute it centers the div perfectly but the nav bar is not visible anymore. I would be grateful if someone could help me!
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>RATA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img class="Logo" src="images/R-white.png" alt="Skull-Logo">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav__links">
          <li><a href="#">Roadmap</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Mint</button></a>
    </header>
    <div class="Start">
    <img class="background" src="images/RATA-small.svg" alt="RATA">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');

/************** PARAM SELECTORS ******************/

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/*******************CLASS SELECTORS*****************/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #191919;
  z-index: 1;
}

li, a, button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
}

.Logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav__links {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav__links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav__links li a:hover {
  color: #0088a9;
}


.cta button {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.cta button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8)
}

/**Div**/
.Start {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/** Image in Div**/
.background {
  margin-top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0
}
```

Comment: If you don't want the navbar to cover the top of your div, you can add some margin or padding at the top.

Comment: I’m not quite clear what you are aiming for. Is the image to start at the very top of the viewport and the nav to show at the top too? Is there a reason for not putting the image as an actual background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to scroll to see the full image in the div.

That sounds like the image height is simply too large for your screen, here I set it to 200px:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');

/************** PARAM SELECTORS ******************/

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/*******************CLASS SELECTORS*****************/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #191919;
  z-index: 1;
}

li, a, button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
}

.Logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav__links {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav__links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav__links li a:hover {
  color: #0088a9;
}


.cta button {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.cta button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8)
}

/**Div**/
.Start {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;

}

/** Image in Div**/
.background {
  margin-top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>RATA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img class="Logo" src="images/R-white.png" alt="Skull-Logo">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav__links">
          <li><a href="#">Roadmap</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Mint</button></a>
    </header>
    <div class="Start">
    <img class="background" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648852071390-7a17e3f2580a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Click the Full Page button to see the snippet in full screen of your device

Comment: Thanks mate! I thought I would have already tried it :D